# Tcl multiple numerical starts within same string

Tags: list, sorting, tcl

How do I do this in tcl
Say I have a list $list1 containing 5 such entries
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_bl_**X8**Y0/wrap_bl_X0Y0_R0/Isine_MY/core
blah_1_X**13**Y2_R0/Isi_bl_**X5**Y0/wrap_bl_X0Y0_R0/Isine_MY/core
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_br_**X7**Y0/wrap_br_X1Y0_R0/Isine_R0/core
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_bl_**X17**Y0/wrap_bl_X0Y0_R0/Isine_MY/core
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_br_**X15**Y0/wrap_br_X1Y0_R0/Isine_R0/core

I want to sort them numerically and output to be like this

```
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_br_**X7**Y0/wrap_br_X1Y0_R0/Isine_R0/core
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_bl_**X8**Y0/wrap_bl_X0Y0_R0/Isine_MY/core
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_br_**X15**Y0/wrap_br_X1Y0_R0/Isine_R0/core
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_bl_**X17**Y0/wrap_bl_X0Y0_R0/Isine_MY/core
blah_1_**X13**Y2_R0/Isi_bl_**X5**Y0/wrap_bl_X0Y0_R0/Isine_MY/core
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This sounds almost like a job for `lsort -dictionary`, yet we need a bit of work to extract the numeric parts because we *don't* seem to want to sort on the non-numeric parts. (I'm assuming you've got your data in a list variable called `data`.)

```
# Extract the parts we want to sort on
set nums [lmap item $data {
    # The collation key is a list of all digit sequences in the input value
    regexp -all -inline {\d+} $item
}]
# Sort and remap back onto the original data
set sorted_data [lmap idx [lsort -dictionary -indices $nums] {
    lindex $data $idx
}]
```

The `-indices` option is *very* useful for when you have a collation key (something you've extracted from the data that you want to sort on) as it means that you don't need to zip that into the original data to do the sort. And `lmap` is just so useful for these sorts of things.

---

The collation key extracted from:

```
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_bl_X8Y0/wrap_bl_X0Y0_R0/Isine_MY/core
```

is:

```
1 11 2 0 8 0 0 0 0
```

And I think your data gets sorted as:

```
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_br_X7Y0/wrap_br_X1Y0_R0/Isine_R0/core
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_bl_X8Y0/wrap_bl_X0Y0_R0/Isine_MY/core
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_br_X15Y0/wrap_br_X1Y0_R0/Isine_R0/core
blah_1_X11Y2_R0/Isi_bl_X17Y0/wrap_bl_X0Y0_R0/Isine_MY/core
blah_1_X13Y2_R0/Isi_bl_X5Y0/wrap_bl_X0Y0_R0/Isine_MY/core
```

If that's not quite correct, a more complex method of picking out the collation key should do the trick.

Comment: It's missing any `*` characters in the input; I fully admit I cut-n-paste with the least effort possible!

Comment: Thanks Donal . I shall try it out